# PostgreSQL Replication disconnects after deleting DB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, repmgr

I've got a PostgreSQL Replication set up using Repmgr.

Replication works fine, until one of the databases is deleted on the master node.

Standby replica throws off 'WAL cannot be found' error and disconnects from the Upstream which causes a major issue for the failover system.
Standby replicas won't recover unless postgres directory is wiped clean and the database is fully cloned from the master again.

PostgreSQL version: 12.5

Repmgr version: 5.1.0

System: CentOS 7

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please quote the exact error messages from the log verbatim.

Comment: Dropping databases works fine with replication.  It does not even generate much WAL. 
Whatever your problem is (which you haven't given enough details about) is probably merely coincidental to the database drop.

Comment: "2021-06-03 14:18:40.235 CEST [66313]   LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at E46/EC000000 on timeline 1

2021-06-03 14:18:40.235 CEST [66313]   FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000E46000000EC has already been removed
"
This is the kind of error that I get in postgres log